# SubSonic 3.0.0.2 Structs.tt

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, t4

The error I'm getting seems to be coming out of the Structs.tt file. I'm using the Northwind db and only using the Products table (I excluded all other tables). I return Json(Product.All()).

Here's the error:

> A circular reference was detected
>   while serializing an object of type
>   'SubSonic.Schema.DatabaseColumn'.Here's
>   the Stack Trace:
>
> System.InvalidOperationException was
>   unhandled by user code Message="A
>   circular reference was detected while
>   serializing an object of type
>   'SubSonic.Schema.DatabaseColumn'."
>   Source="System.Web.Extensions"
>   StackTrace: at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeEnumerable(IEnumerable
>   enumerable, StringBuilder sb, Int32
>   depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeEnumerable(IEnumerable
>   enumerable, StringBuilder sb, Int32
>   depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeCustomObject(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth,
>   Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj, StringBuilder output,
>   SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj, SerializationFormat
>   serializationFormat) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult
>   actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass11.b__e()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter
>   filter, ResultExecutingContext
>   preContext, Func1 continuation) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass11.<>c__DisplayClass13.b__10()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList1 filters,
>   ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext
>   requestContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler.VerifyAndProcessRequest(IHttpHandler
>   httpHandler, HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) at
>   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext) at
>   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   httpContext) at
>   System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context) at
>   ExtJSNorthwind._Default.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Applications\Spikes\ExtJSNorthwind\ExtJSNorthwind\Default.aspx.cs:line
>   18 at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr
>   fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
>   at
>   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs
>   e) at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   InnerException:

Comment: This is the message of the exception:
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'SubSonic.Schema.DatabaseColumn'.

Comment: Don't know if this will help to solve the problem, but as I dug deeper into the exception I ran into this:

Message: "Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."

FullName: System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: This sounds very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153385/a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-subsonic-s

Comment: Reading that post the answer was to select specific fields to return.  My problem is I need the ProductID and the code fails when it reaches the GetKeyColumn() method in ActiveRecord.cs where it returns the ProductID.  The breakpoints on the Structs.cs for the ProductID column are passing.

Comment: Sound the same as my issue I assumed the circular reference was the fact that we have IQueryable foreign key references and it was stuck in a loop when serializing? I changed it to return only specific columns and it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems we have an issue with Serialization :). Can you please add this as an Issue on our list? I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I posted it to GitHub and it is now issue #82.

Thanks Rob.

Comment: Check out the fix that I posted below.  GitHub was as slow as mud or i would have posted it there too.

Answer (score 16):

This is fairly easy to fix.  You need to just add a ScriptIgnore attribute to a couple of the methods in the ActiveRecord.tt file.  Below are the changes that I made.

```
        [ScriptIgnore]
    public IList<IColumn> Columns{
        get{
            return tbl.Columns;
        }
    }
```

Note: I also added the attribute to the following method though I don't know if it is needed in your situation

```
        [ScriptIgnore]
    public IQueryable<<#=fk.OtherClass #>> <#=propName #>
    {
        get
        {

              var repo=<#=Namespace #>.<#=fk.OtherClass#>.GetRepo();
              return from items in repo.GetAll()
                   where items.<#=CleanUp(fk.OtherColumn)#> == _<#=CleanUp(fk.ThisColumn)#>
                   select items;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ScriptIgnore attibute is in System.Web.Extensions
this is definitely the best solution if you want to serializate the whole object, but I came to realize that when using JSon you won't often use the whole object. Still I'm going to use this for sure.

Comment: Thanks! Although I hope there's a better solution this is an awesome _temporary_ fix.

Comment: @woopstash I think the "better" solution is probably to use a DTO or other object to serialize it. In my case, I have 3 properties and I just need to [ScriptIgnore] the one that refers back to the parent... so this is a perfectly reasonable solution for me

Comment: @runxc1 Bret Ferrier : where to place right location for [ScriptIgnore]