# How to return a new object of a concrete type using LINQ/Linq2E?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have the following select statement which appears syntactically correct:

```
 var accounts = from i in db.IRSBASEFLs
                           join vr in db.VSARules on i.VSACode equals vr.VSACode into rules
                           from rule in rules.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           select new ImporterAccount(i, rule, RuleType.Liquidity);
```

However, this throws:

```
Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

I've tried adding a "builder" class to return a new ImporterAccount, but this too fails, this time with:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'IrsalDAL.ImporterAccount CreateImporterAccount(IrsalDAL.IRSBASEFL, IrsalDAL.VSARule, IrsalUtilities.RuleType)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I need to perform a calculation, ideally in the constructor, so I am a little confused as to how to acheive this?

Why is this throwing a L2E exception when the class is not part of my entity model?

How can I return a new object and perform a calculation on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure what the solution to your problem is, but you can work around it as such:

```
var tempAccounts = from i in db.IRSBASEFLs
                   join vr in db.VSARules on i.VSACode equals vr.VSACode into rules
                   from rule in rules.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new { VarI = i, Rule = rule, Liquidity = RuleType.Liquidity};

var accounts = tempAccounts.Select(x => new ImporterAccount(x.VarI, x.rule, x.Liquidity));
```

Hope it helps :)

**Edit 1:**
Regarding the "close existing data reader error", [A google search returns many results](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=There%20is%20already%20an%20open%20DataReader%20associated%20with%20this%20Command%20which%20must%20be%20closed%20first%20linq%202%20entities&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a), with the first one being a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comman). The accepted answer is:

> It is not about closing connection. EF manages connection correctly.
>   My understanding of this problem is that there are multiple data
>   retrieval commands executed on single connection (or single command
>   with multiple selects) while next DataReader is executed before first
>   one has completed the reading. The only way to avoid the exception is
>   to allow multiple nested DataReaders = turn on
>   MultipleActiveResultSets. Another scenario when this always happens is
>   when you iterate through result of the query (IQueryable) and you will
>   trigger lazy loading for loaded entity inside the iteration.

Comment: Thank you, however I get "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first" ?

Comment: This seems to be a separate issue. I have edited my answer with a link to a possible solution.

Comment: Accdepted your answer, although I actually returned everything into an anonymouse type first, then selected from this to get round the second problem (which was both lazy loading and multiple result sets)