# How can I defind that object set was already created?

Tags: mysql, database, entity-framework, datareader

I'm working with entity framework and mysql. We created a class

```
public class DataBaseContext : ObjectContext, IDbContext
```

There is a method

```
 public IEnumerable<T> Find<T>(Func<T, bool> whereClause) where T : class
        {
            return CreateObjectSet<T>().Where(whereClause);
        }
```

Is there a way not to create ObjectSet every time when I call the method? Can I check that it is already exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whooooo. That is so bad method. You are passing `Func<>`, not `Expression<Func<>>`. It means that every time you execute your method EF will pull all records from database table mapped to `T` and execute your filtering in memory of your application - creating object set is the last thing you should be afraid of.

Anyway creating object set should not be expensive operation and if you don't want to create it every time you need to implement some "local caching" inside your object context instance.

Comment: The reason why I was trying to do that is not a perfomance. I have a "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first." exception and trying somehow overcome this problem

Comment: That problem is absolutely unrelated with object set. You are either using your context instance for concurrent operations (multiple threads) or you have problem mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comman/4868569#4868569).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I alredy saw that post yesterday. Now I'm trying to figure out how can that help me