# Strange EF behaviour when passing DbSet to a method with parameter type IEnumerable<>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a repository class which is querying the EF DbContext like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductFilterData> GetAllProducts()
{
   return this.DataContext.Products.Select(x => new ProductFilterData { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, ProductDetailLevelCode = x.ProductDetailLevel.Code, Description = x.Description, ParentProductIds = x.ParentProducts.Select(p => p.Id) });
}
```

Which works fine. However, when I refactor this code to this:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductFilterData> GetAllProducts()
{
    return this.MapToProductFilterData(this.DataContext.Products);
}

private IEnumerable<ProductFilterData> MapToProductFilterData(IEnumerable<Product> products)
{
    return products.Select(x => new ProductFilterData { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name, ProductDetailLevelCode = x.ProductDetailLevel.Code, Description = x.Description, ParentProductIds = x.ParentProducts.Select(p => p.Id) });
}
```

I get an exception:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

Why does passing a reference to the DbSet to a method cause a change in the behavior of EF? Incidentally, if I change the parameter type of MapToProductFilterData to IQueryable then it works. Also, if I remove the relationship mappings it also works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must change it to `IQueryable` because if you pass it as `IEnumerable` you actually execute query `SELECT * FROM Product`. Your method starts iterating the result set but your projection calls `x.ParentProducts.Select(p => p.Id)` which results in lazy loading of `ParentProducts` navigation property. Lazy loading opens second active data reader which is possible only if you have it [enabled in connection string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma/4868569#4868569).

Comment: Thanks. To clarify your point, a different Select extension method is being executed (the one for IEnumerable<> rather than IQueryable<>), which results in the different behavior.