# Entity Framework LINQ SelectMany exception

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

Why does Entity Framework (4.1), with the data model you might expect behind the following query, return an InvalidOperationException ("There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first") on this?

```
((IEnumerable<Company>)db.Companies).SelectMany(x => x.Department).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is likely not a problem.  You may need to turn on the MultipleActiveResultSets attribute in your connection string.  [Check out the answer for this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma)

Answer (score 0):

Because using Linq to EF as an IEnumerable mantains a DataReader open, thus you can't make other queries before closing it. Try materializing the collection as an IList, like this:

```
db.Companies.ToList().SelectMany(x => x.Department).ToList();
```

Comment: You can make this one: ((IEnumerable<Company>)db.Companies).Where(x => x.Name == "IBM").ToList()

Comment: @stovroz: Why do you use this cast in the first place?

Comment: @BrokenGlass. The cast is to simulate the db call being inside a GetCompanies() function of that return type.

Comment: Can't you change that to return an IQueryable instead? That way, your query won't be run until you hit .ToList()

Comment: any difference if you turn MARS on in the conn string?

Comment: @James, it does indeed. Many thanks. And sorry if your comment pre-dates Bear's answer, which I'm about to accept.