# Refresh the Data within ObjectContext in the entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, refresh

I'm trying to refresh data within my EntityFramework ObjectSet but I'm receiving the following error: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

So I have a ObjectContext which returns me an ObjectSet of customers. That list of customers I then stick into a grid. Below is a snippet from my method:

```
public class CustomerEntity : SECValidation.SECEntity
{
    ObjectSet<Customer> objectCustomer;

    public override void InitialiseObject()
    {
        objectCustomer = myObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<Customer>("Customers");
        objectCustomer.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
    }

    public override List<T> SelectRecords<T>()
    {
       return (from custDetails in objectCustomer.Include("Owner_Lookup")
           .Include("Business_Type_Lookup").Include("Assets").Include("Client")
           select custDetails).Cast<T>().ToList();
    }

        public override T SelectRecordByUNID<T>(int UN_ID)
        {
            return (from custDetails in objectCustomer.Include("Owner_Lookup").Include("Business_Type_Lookup").Include("Assets").Include("Client")
                    where custDetails.UN_Customer == UN_ID
                    select custDetails).Cast<T>().SingleOrDefault();
        }
}
```

So I create an instance of my CustomerEntity class and call InitialiseObject(). After that I call SelectRecords() which provides the results for my grid.

I have code on the SelectedIndex changed event on the grid which calls the method SelectRecordByUNID passing in the customerID of the selected row. This selects a customer record which is used elsewhere.

Now if somebody updates the data elsewhere (another instance of the app) I would like to refresh my objectCustomer to see those changes.

However the SelectRecords method runs OK, but when the SelectRecordByUNID method is called it fails with the error I mentioned above. The error says that there is an associated DataReader already open with this command and to close it. How can I get rounds this without closing the Data Reader as other data is opened which is related to the datasource of the customer grid?

I use myObjectContext to create object set for different entities too.

I'm using c# and .Net4.0

Help me please and I hope that makes sense!?!

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma)

Comment: Not sure if it is or not to be honest. I've tried setting MultipleActiveResultSets=True and that makes no difference. Thanks for your reply

Comment: In such case you must provide more information in your question because you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: OK, I've updated the question if that helps. Let me know if not.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange error because your query is executed by `ToList` and `DataReader` should be closed.

Try to not use `Refresh` in this case. You are executing query anyway so try this instead:

```
public override List<T> SelectRecords<T>()
{
   objectCustomer.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
   return (from custDetails in objectCustomer.Include("Owner_Lookup")
       .Include("Business_Type_Lookup").Include("Assets").Include("Client")
       select custDetails).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That works for my customer grid now but it seems to have pushed the error else where. I've updated the job to reflect this. Thanks again