# Deleting from a SQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I'm trying to delete an assignment from a MySQL db. While doing so I'm deleting all elements and boguses as seen below. Problem is that when it gets to the for-loop in the deleteboguses method it throws an exception "EntityCommandExecutionException" any ideas why it does this? What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void DeleteAssignment(int id)
    {
        var deleteAssignment = from assignment in context.assignment
                               where assignment.id == id
                               select assignment;
        DeleteElement(id);
        foreach (assignment a in deleteAssignment)
        {
            context.assignment.DeleteObject(a);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static void DeleteElement(int id)
    {
        var deleteElement = from element in context.element
                            where element.assId == id
                            select element;
        foreach(var e in deleteElement)
        {
            DeleteBoguses(e.id);
            context.element.DeleteObject(e);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public static void DeleteBoguses(int id)
    {
        var deleteBogus = from b in context.bogus
                          where b.elementId == id
                          select b;
        foreach(var b in deleteBogus)
        {
            context.bogus.DeleteObject(b);
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: Hello! :) Please post the exception and the message associated with it too.

Comment: System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled
  Message=An error occurred while executing the command definition.   See the inner exception for details.

Comment: What is the inner exception ?

Comment: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma). You need to set `MultipleActiveResultSets ` to true.

Comment: This indicates that an effort is done to do a database read while other objects are in a state of being read and materialized from the database. Multiple active result sets may help, but usually it can also be prevented by forcing execution of a linq statement. Here, doing `deleteBogus.ToList()` may help.

Comment: Thx alot, the last answer helped when i tried doing it to deleteElement.ToList() in the deleteElement(int id) method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as an explanation for the reason why you needed this fix, and this question is still technically open.

`IEnumerable`, like the `deleteElement` variable in your `DeleteElement` method, will not accept the user deleting items from its collection while enumerating through the values.

To get around this, you use the `ToList()` function to create a copy of the values. This make it safe to delete items in the original list while still looping though its values.