# How to fix this "already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first" in my Linq-statement?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Entity Framework: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma)

I have these classes:

```
    public class VwSelectBrochures
{
    public List<SelectBrochure> SelectBrochures { get; set; }
}

   public class SelectBrochure
{
    public int BrochureId { get; set; }
    public string UrlImage { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Cat1Description { get; set; }
    public string Cat2Description { get; set; }
    public string Cat3Description { get; set; }
    public List<LangSelection> Languages { get; set; }
}

public class LangSelection
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Vink { get; set; }
}
```

and this line of code:

```
var dbmodel2 =
from x in
    brochures.AsEnumerable().Select(
        x => new SelectBrochure {BrochureId = x.Id, Description = x.Description, UrlImage = x.UrlImage,
        Languages = new List<LangSelection>(from y in x.BrochureLanguages select new LangSelection(){Description = y.Language.Description, Id = y.Language.Id})})
select x;
```

Brochures and BrochureLanguages are my db-models.

I know I get the error, because I can't do the "from y in x.BrochureLanguages", but I don't see how I can fix this.

What I really want is to get all the brochures into the VwSelectBrochures class.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't declare and build the List<LanguageSelection> before this statement and then just issue a .ToArray().ToList() on that list for each new SelectBrochure? **For that matter you could declare it as an array up above and just issue a .ToList() on that array for every new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to bring the whole `brochures` into the memory (using `ToList()`) first:

```
var dbmodel2 =
from x in
    brochures.ToList().Select(
        x => new SelectBrochure {BrochureId = x.Id, Description = x.Description, UrlImage = x.UrlImage,
        Languages = new List<LangSelection>(from y in x.BrochureLanguages select new LangSelection(){Description = y.Language.Description, Id = y.Language.Id})})
select x;
```

This way when running `from y in ...` there is no other DataReader open. I think there is another option using a `join`.

Comment: You, sir, are fantastic! I should've found that.

Comment: @jurgen_be Please mark as accepted answer if that solves the problem. Please refer to [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

There is too little information to recommend an architectural fix, but a workaround would be to enable [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28VS.80%29.aspx) in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unsure of query expressions and personally prefer to use the underlying extension methods to obtain results.  So I am sorry this answer is not in query expression format, but could you try it?

```
    var dbmodel2 = brochures.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new SelectBrochure {
        BrochureId = x.Id, 
        Description = x.Description, 
        UrlImage = x.UrlImage,
        Languages = x.BrochureLanguages.Select(y => new LangSelection() {
            Description = y.Language.Description, 
            Id = y.Language.Id
        })
    }).ToList(); // this executes the whole query
```

Again, not being 100% sure about the query expression format, I felt the outer "from x in ... select x" was superfluous and wondered if that may have caused the error.

Comment: Simple adaptation worked flawlessly: adding ToList after "brochures." and same after y.Language.ID}).ToList()