# Entity Framework exception when looping through entities (works when using ToList( ), though)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, lazy-loading

I have a table of entities called MyItems, and each item in this table has a foreign key to another table. I'd like to simply loop through my items and access the string 'Name' property of each item's foreign key object, like so:

```
foreach (var myItem in (from q in context.MyItems select q))
{
   string testName = myItem.ForeignItem.Name
}
```

When I do this, ForeignItem is null, and I get an InvalidOperationException when I attempt to access ForeignItem:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which
>   must be closed first.

***However*** - if I instead call ToList() like so:

```
(from q in context.MyItems select q).ToList()
```

my foreign key objects populate just fine. I realise that ToList() is going to be expensive, since the whole table is going to be retrieved at once. I suspect that something is going wrong behind the scenes with lazy loading, but I'm working with the understanding that it *should* work without calling `ToList()`.

Have I overlooked something?

**Edit:** I was thinking perhaps the use of `var` was causing problems, so I tried using

```
foreach (MyItem myItem in (from q in context.MyItems select q))
{
   // loop contents
}
```

instead - same results. The properties of `myItem` are populated except for the foreign key objects, which remain null.

**Edit #2:** I only ever use one object context, and one Linq-to-Entities statement in my entire application, so I'm at a loss to explain where this other DataReader is operating. I should also note that this error happens for the first object in the loop, so it's not as a result of a previous item being retrieved.

Comment: Is ForeignItem.Name something that needs to be eager loaded?

Comment: have you tried putting myItem.ForeignItem.Load(); before you actually try to fetch the ForeignItem.Name value ?

Comment: @Brian It should be loaded, period. Why it works when I call `ToList()` but not when I don't is the big question.

Comment: @Jane Doe Even if `ForeignItem` exposed such a method, `ForeignItem` is null, so I'd be calling an instance method on a null object.

Comment: so myItem.ForeignItem doesnt expose .Load(); or .LoadForeignItemReference()?

Comment: @Jane Doe No, `ForeignItem` inherits from [`EntityObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.aspx).

Comment: the mechanics behind ToList are different than just doing a foreach loop.  Just because it eager loads in a ToList doesn't mean it will eager load in other usages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote `myItem` instead of `q`. You should use this:

```
(from q in context.MyItems select q)
```

Or more simply, you can just write this:

```
context.MyItems
```

---

Regarding your updated question, it seems to be because you start a new query before the first has finished executing. Possible solutions:

- Include the child items when you run the original query.

  ```
  foreach (var myItem in context.MyItems.Include("ForeignItem")) { ... }
  ```
- Enable MultipleActiveResultSets.

**Related**

- [Entity Framework: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma)

Comment: I was sanitizing my object names for SO, the typo was irrelevant to the problem. I've updated the code in the question.

Comment: Isn't there also an issue of delayed execution?  IIRC, LINQ queries defer their execution until they're acted upon via something like a ToList/ToArray.  Would a ForEach force execution?

Comment: @kevinmajor1 Yes, `foreach` will force execution.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Include() seems to accept string parameters only. I suspect that that code is not correct. I'll try using the type name as specified in the [relevant MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing, as per Mark's suggestion to use [Include( )](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx):

```
(from q in context.MyItems.Include("ForeignItemOne").Include("ForeignItemTwo").Include("ForeignItemThree") select q)
```

Incidently, setting `MultipleActiveResultSets` to true also works. For now, I'll use `Include()` since the application is small and only has one Linq statement in it.