# Attribute of LINQ result is NULL but relationship is working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have set up 3 models, code first and the relationships seem to be working but one is causing me a problem.

I have Article, Language and Edition Classes

```
public class Article
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class Edition
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Article Article  { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }        
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

In my bootstrap/DBinitialiser, I can create Objects and populate them fine. The DB is created and the foreign keys for Language and Article are both present on the Edition table and correctly entered.

```
var engLang = new Language() {Code="en", Name="English Language"};
var altLang = new Language() {Code="xx", Name="Alternative Language"};
db.Languages.Add(engLang);
db.Languages.Add(altLang);
db.SaveChanges();

var testArt = new Article() { Name = "test" };
db.Articles.Add(testArt);
db.SaveChanges();

db.Editions.Add(new Edition(){Article = testArt, Language = engLang, Title="English Content"});
db.Editions.Add(new Edition(){Article = testArt, Language = altLang, Title="Alternative Content"});
db.SaveChanges();
```

I can now query the Editions and return a list of them, but the Language attribute is always NULL. The Article Attribute works fine.

```
 var query = db.Editions.Where(r => r.Article.ID == Article.ID);

 foreach (Edition item in query)
 {
    // item.Language => NULL
    // item.Article => {Object Article}         
 }
```

I'm new to .net and Entity-Framework and can't work out why I always get this error. 
I can even query by r => r.Language.ID == 1  and still get a NULL attribute on the Edition object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With thanks to AmirHossein Mehrvarzi for helping me write my models more clearly, I believe this error to be caused by the lazy loading of entities while iterating through the result of the query. ref: [Entity Framework: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/).

Without enabling `MultipleActiveResultSets` I simply added an **Include** statement to my linq

```
var query = db.Editions.Where(r => r.Article.ID == Article.ID).Include(r => r.Language);

foreach (Edition item in query)
{
    // item.Language => {Object Language}
    // item.Article => {Object Article}         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using EF codefirst in right manner. Here you have some ambiguities. You must determine what relationships actually should exist, in your POCOs. Change classes like bellow:

```
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}

public class Language
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class Edition
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article  { get; set; }
    public virtual Language Language { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }        
    public string Details { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That has helped me write my models better and the result is now no longer NULL. However the result is now: `'item.Language' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException'` in addition, I have the message `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.` Which I believe is referring to lazy loading in the for loop?

Comment: To solve multiple DataReader add this to your connection string : MultipleActiveResultSets=true; This is Recommended by default in EF.