# Threads and linq data context

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq

This is my code:

```
DatabaseDataContext context = new DatabaseDataContext();

var sourceList = (from q in context.Table1 where col1< 2000 select q).ToList();

foreach( Type x in sourceList)
{
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FetchData(x));
}

FetchData(x)
{
    SomeBO obj = new SomeBO();

    obj.Prop1 = x.Table2.col;
    obj.Prop2 = x.Table3.col;
}
```

When I execute this code, I get an exception 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first'. How could I make the method 'FetchData' to execute in parallel for all the list item in 'sourceList'?

Answer (score 1):

You are using one context instance in multiple threads. But a context is not thread safe. Switching on MARS won't help, the tasks will keep competing for the connections.

The solution is to create a new context for each task. Maybe something like

```
FetchData(x)
{
    SomeBO obj = new SomeBO();
    using(var context = new DatabaseDataContext())
    {
        obj.Prop1 = context.Table2s.Where(t2 => t2.Id == x.Id)
                           .FirstOrDefault().col;
        ...
    }
}
```

but I have to guess, because I don't know the structure of your classes.

Answer (score 0):

> 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first'

You could have a look at a link [Entity Framework - There is already an open data reader associated with this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma)

> How could I make the method 'FetchData' to execute in parallel for all the list item in 'sourceList'?

I think you want [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx)

Comment: How would it solve the problem `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first`

Comment: As @I4V said, it didn't solve the problem. still the exception is thrown

Comment: Plz, have a look at link I gave you. And then you can use Parallel.ForEach().

Comment: @ckr you *need* to add [MARS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16731616/1244816) to the connextionstring.

Answer (score 0):

You properly need to include [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your connectionstring. 
Like this:

```
 var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
          {
            DataSource = "myServer",
            InitialCatalog = "mydatabase",
            IntegratedSecurity = false,
            UserID = "user",
            Password = "pass",
            MultipleActiveResultSets = true //<-- here
          };
```

and then

```
   var efConnString = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
          {
            ProviderConnectionString = sqlBuilder.ToString()
           //other properties omitted
          }
```

Or you could do it the old-fashion-way:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=MSSQL1;" + 
    "Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI" +
    "MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```