# IQueryable in foreach - open DataReader error

Tags: entity-framework, foreach, nullpointerexception, iqueryable, igrouping

When i run this code

```
public PartialViewResult GetHardware()
{
        IQueryable<Hardware> hardware = db.Hardwares;

        HardwareState hwState = new HardwareState();
        IQueryable<IGrouping<string, Hardware>> groupByCategory = hardware.GroupBy(g => g.Category);

        foreach (IGrouping<string, Hardware> group in groupByCategory)
        {
            hwState.GroupName = group.Key;
            hwState.GroupUnitsCount = group.Count();

            hwState.StorageReservedCount
                = group.Where(m =>
                m.Place.IsStorage == true &&
                m.PlaceID != (int)Constants.HardwareState.Created &&
                m.HardwareState == (int)Constants.HardwareState.Reserved).Count();

        }
        return PartialView(hwState);
}
```

I get an error about that the navigation property `m.Place = null`

when i transfer some of the text with the code of the foreach block

```
public PartialViewResult GetHardware()
{
        IQueryable<Hardware> hardware = db.Hardwares;

        HardwareState hwState = new HardwareState();
        IQueryable<IGrouping<string, Hardware>> groupByCategory = hardware.GroupBy(g => g.Category);

        hwState.StorageReservedCount
                = hardware.Where(m =>
                m.Place.IsStorage == true &&
                m.PlaceID != (int)Constants.HardwareState.Created &&
                m.HardwareState == (int)Constants.HardwareState.Reserved).Count();


        foreach (IGrouping<string, Hardware> group in groupByCategory)
        {
            hwState.GroupName = group.Key;
            hwState.GroupUnitsCount = group.Count();
        }
        return PartialView(hwState);
}
```

,the navigation property is **not set to null** and the error does not appear

Extension methods such as `.AsQueryable` or `Include(x => x.Place)` do not help me

How can i solve this problem?

**UPDATE:** If i change the type to `IEnumerable` instead `IQueryable` it begins to work!

but i would like to work with the `IQueryable` type

**UPDATE2:** I'm sorry, i did not put it correctly when i  wrote that the error is an empty navigation property. Error that appears in fact 
**"There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."** 
As described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602) it is because: (quote)

> "Another scenario when this always happens is when you iterate through
>   result of the query (IQueryable) and you will trigger lazy loading for
>   loaded entity inside the iteration."

But it does not say how to solve the problem without using ToList () or MARS

Comment: When you say Include(x => x.Place) does not help, can you explain why?

Comment: I've updated the content of the question, UPDATE 2