# Dynamically calling collections with different types from a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, dynamic, collections

I will try to summarize what I'm trying to do first in text.
I have a dictionary of DbSets that has a value of other collections (in my case either a IEnumerable or List). Through a foreach loop, Im trying to access the DbSet first to see if it contains 'Any' items. If this is not the case, then I want to continue to the value, so that I can add defined values within a IEnumerable/List into the DbSet. At last, I save changes with EntityFrameworkCore. However, some I cannot access these DbSets or Collections, since during run-time they needed to be solved. Maybe you have a better way of doing this, because the entities differ from each other that are present as keys and values within the dictionary... So what I was actually expecting was that it would be possible to gain access to these DbSets (keys)/Collections (values) in a dynamic way, where I do not have to declare types on beforehand. A dictionary does only allow a single type, so I decided to go for a 'dynamic' type. I didn't know what other options are there to do this a little bit clean...

Let me summarize first which types I have for the DbSets (which are keys in my dictionary):

- (KEY 1) '**configContext!.Clients**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.Client
- (KEY 2) '**configContext!.IdentityResources**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.IdentityResource
- (KEY 3) '**configContext!.ApiScopes**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.ApiScope
- (KEY 4) '**configContext!.ApiResources**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.ApiResource

For the values, other types are being used

- (VALUE OF KEY 1) '**Config.Clients**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.Models.Client
- (VALUE OF KEY 2) '**Config.IdentityResources**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.Models.IdentityResource
- (VALUE OF KEY 3) '**Config.ApiScopes**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.Models.ApiScope
- (VALUE OF KEY 4) '**Config.ApiResources**' has actual type: Duende.IdentityServer.Models.ApiResource

**NOTE**

Although I have different types each key can be mapped from model to entity or from entity to model. So keys and values have 1:1 relationship. Difference between keys and values is that Keys are Database Entities and Values are Models

**My initial code:**

*Using part:*

```
    using Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.DbContexts;
    using Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Mappers;
    using Duende.IdentityServer.Models;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using DbClient = Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.Client;
    using DbIdentityResource = Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.IdentityResource;
    using DbApiScope = Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.ApiScope;
    using DbApiResource = Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entitie  s.ApiResource;
```

*Test method:*

```
    private static void Test(this ConfigurationDbContext configContext)
        {
            Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> configCollections = new Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>()
            {
                { configContext!.Clients, Config.Clients },
                { configContext!.IdentityResources, Config.IdentityResources },
                { configContext!.ApiScopes, Config.ApiScopes },
                { configContext!.ApiResources, Config.ApiResources },
            };

            foreach (var configCollection in configCollections)
            {
                var collection = configCollection!.Key.Any();

                if (collection == false)
                {
                    foreach (var configValue in configCollection.Value)
                    {
                        configCollection!.Key.Add(configValue.ToEntity());
                    }

                    configContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

**How is the code being called (initial version)**

```
    configContext.Test();
```

**Initial error I received, before making any new attempts:**

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.Client>' does not contain a definition for 'Any''

**What I have tried to fix it, but without success**

*MY NEW 1ST ATTEMPT: (first changed dictionary and then method call)*

Test Method looked like this:

```
    private static void Test<T1, T2, T3, T4, K1, K2, K3, K4>(this ConfigurationDbContext configContext)
```

My new dictionary:

```
    Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic> configCollections = new Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>()
            {
                { configContext!.Clients.Cast<T1>(), Config.Clients.Cast<K1>() },
                { configContext!.IdentityResources.Cast<T2>(), Config.IdentityResources.Cast<K2>()  },
                { configContext!.ApiScopes.Cast<T3>(), Config.ApiScopes.Cast<K3>() },
                { configContext!.ApiResources.Cast<T4>(), Config.ApiResources.Cast<K4>() },
            };
```

Method call:

```
    configContext.Test<DbClient, DbIdentityResource, DbApiScope, DbApiResource, Client, IdentityResource, ApiScope, ApiResource>();
```

*MY NEW 2ND ATTEMPT:*
changed **var collection** to ->

```
    ((DbSet<dynamic>)configCollection!.Key).Any();
```

*MY NEW 3RD ATTEMPT:*
changed **var collection** to ->

```
    ((DbSet<dynamic>) configCollection!.Key).Cast<dynamic>().Any();
```

**New errors I have achieved...**

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot convert type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.Client>' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet''

Does anyone have a clue about what is going on? I'd appreciate it.

**UPDATE: SOLVED PROBLEM THROUGH CODE BELOW:**

*Note:*

1. using **Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Mappers** has different mappers per config type (just mentioning, because they do not exist under Mappers and exist in a deeper layer in Mappers)
2. Make sure to add the following to your connection string "**MultipleActiveResultSets=true;**"

```
    public static void TestExec()
        {
            List<(IQueryable dbSet, IEnumerable<object> models)> configCollections = new() 
            {
                (configContext!.Clients, Config.Clients),
                (configContext!.IdentityResources, Config.IdentityResources),
                (configContext!.ApiScopes, Config.ApiScopes),
                (configContext!.ApiResources, Config.ApiResources),
            };

            foreach (var (dbSet, models) in configCollections)
            {
                if (dbSet.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator().MoveNext() == false)
                { 
                    foreach (object configValue in models)
                    {
                        dynamic? test = null;

                        switch (configValue.GetType().Name)
                        {
                            case nameof(Client):
                                test = ClientMappers.ToEntity((dynamic)configValue);
                                break;
                            case nameof(IdentityResource):
                            case nameof(OpenId):
                            case nameof(Profile):
                            case nameof(Email):
                            case nameof(Phone):
                            case nameof(Address):
                                test = IdentityResourceMappers.ToEntity((dynamic)configValue);
                                break;
                            case nameof(ApiScope):
                                test = ScopeMappers.ToEntity((dynamic)configValue);
                                break;
                            case nameof(ApiResource):
                                test = ApiResourceMappers.ToEntity((dynamic)configValue);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }

                        ((dynamic)dbSet).Add(test!);
                        
                    }

                    configContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what the keys are. Are they an object of some type or should they be the very type of this object?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes They are 'DbSets' and in the very beginning of my question I summarized which types I have, so that you can see that keys and values differ from each other. Mainly, I just try to access the DbSets and those values (which are other collections) during run-time.. but since I used 'dynamic' as type and I have multiple similar types (1:1 relationship with key and value), somehow during run time keys cannot be mapped... If you have a better approach, please let me know. Difference between keys and values is that Keys are Database Entities and Values are Models.

Comment: I suggest using `Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable>`. Then you can get the key with e.g. `typeof(Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.Client)` or from an object with `obj.GetType()`.

Comment: The thing is, I want to a have listX inside the dictionary as a key that has a value of another list. I do not know the types, so the types should be resolved at run time.. so I cannot use 'typeof(Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.Client)'

Comment: But you can use `list.GetType()` if you interested in the type. But I still do not understand what the key should be: 1. the type of the list, 2. the type of the list items, 3. the list reference, 4. all the values in the list.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes the key is a list reference from configContext but it has all the values from that list. I'm not interested in the type, I just want to be able to call for example 'Any()' on that dynamic key. But I get an error back which I mentioned earlier under 'Initial error I received, before making any new attempts'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether a dictionary is the best choice here. The advantage of a dictionary over a list is that you can lookup a value very quickly (**O(1)**) by using its key. If you are simply enumerating keys or values or key/value-pairs, it is slower than a list (both **O(n)**).

Do not use a dictionary if you simply want to store value pairs. You can do so by storing tuples in a list for example. In the examples you have given, you are never looking up a value by key. *This is what confused me in your question and comments. You never actually use `Key` as a key but only as a storage.*

This shows how you can store the information in a list of tuples:

```cs
List<(IQueryable dbSet, IEnumerable models)> configCollections = new() {
    (configContext!.Clients, Config.Clients),
    (configContext!.IdentityResources, Config.IdentityResources),
    (configContext!.ApiScopes, Config.ApiScopes),
    (configContext!.ApiResources, Config.ApiResources),
};
```

You can then write your test as

```cs
foreach (var (dbSet, models) in configCollections) {
    if (!dbSet.AsQueryable().GetEnumerator().MoveNext()) { // !Any()
        foreach (object configValue in models) {
            ((dynamic)dbSet).Add(((dynamic)configValue).ToEntity());
        }

        configContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

If your config value classes have a common non-generic base class or  interface, then you can use a `IEnumerable<CommonBase>` instead of `IEnumerable`. If the common base contains a non-generic `ToEntity()` method, then you can simplify adding values to the dbset

```cs
            ((dynamic)dbSet).Add(configValue.ToEntity());
```

You can still use a dictionary, but then the key should be the type of the entities you want to retrieve. The dictionary would be declared as

```cs
Dictionary<Type, (IQueryable dbSet, IEnumerable models)> configCollections;
```

and you could retrieve the collections with

```cs
if (configCollections.TryGetValue(typeof(Client), out var collections)) {
    var (dbSet, models) = collections;
    // TODO: Do something with dbSet or models
}
```

Comment: If I run this example, ToEntity(/ToModel) from package: using Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Mappers; is not recognized, whereafter I receive the following message after running: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''Duende.IdentityServer.Models.Client' does not contain a definition for 'ToEntity''

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know this `ToEntity` method. If it is an extension method, try calling `Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Mappers.ToEntity(configValue)` instead. If it is generic, then you will have a problem.

Comment: Ok, basically Duende.IdentityServer provides some mappers and for each separate type you have different mappers. I have declared something like this now: https://ibb.co/zZP55Pq  but if I run this part, the crash happens at "((dynamic)dbSet).Add(test!);" and says the following: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.Client>.Add(Duende.IdentityServer.EntityFramework.Entities.Client)' has some invalid arguments'

Comment: If I change the part "object? test = null;" to "dynamic? test = null;" then somehow it does not crash. This time it crashes at 'configContext.SaveChanges();' and I get the following error... : System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.'

Comment: See: [Entity Framework: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma). Please post new questions if you encounter new problems.

Comment: I was literally about to quote the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867602/entity-framework-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-comma/34185390#34185390

Comment: That is how I solved it now. Your suggestion with that switch case and adding "MultipleActiveResultSets=true" to my connection string, I was able to solve this problem!

Comment: I'll put an overview in my question of how I have solved it now with the help of yours, by sharing the complete code. I appreciate your answer so much, thank you Olivier.

Comment: I have a one last question. I was trying to figure out on my own how I could call something like: dbSet.FirstOrDefault(). However, after running this part of the code I end up with an exception which says that it couldn't find this definition for dbSet. Any ideas how to solve this part?

Comment: This happens because the LINQ extension methods are defined on the generic `IQueryable<T>` interface only. But `dbSet` has the neutral non-generic type `IQueryable`. This dynamic approach will always suffer from this problem. Maybe this article can help. It uses Reflection to do the magic: [Calling Generic Methods from Non-Generic Code in .Net](https://jeremydmiller.com/2020/07/27/calling-generic-methods-from-non-generic-code-in-net/).

Comment: Thank you Olivier. I could not thank you enough for how you helped me through with this. Kind regards