# Passing Database Data from Server to Client using DataTable

Tags: c#, json, serialization, gridview

I have the following server code:

**Methods.cs**

```
public DataTable GetAllCreditCards()
        {
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BankDB"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable data_table = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetAllAccountDetails", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(data_table);
            conn.Close();
            return data_table;
        }
```

**Handler.ashx**

```
if (function.Equals("GetAllCreditCards"))
            {
                DataTable text = m.GetAllCreditCards();

                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                string json = oSerializer.Serialize(text);

                context.Response.Write(json);
            }
```

I have the following client code:

**HomePage.aspx**

```
if (TextBox_Function.Text.Equals("GetAllCreditCards"))
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:4000/Handler.ashx?function=" + TextBox_Function.Text);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                String answer = returnResponse(response);

                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer oSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                DataTable data_table = oSerializer.Deserialize<DataTable>(answer);

                Session["data_table"] = data_table;
                Response.Redirect("Results_Reader.aspx");
            }
```

**Results_Reader.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable data_table = (DataTable)Session["data_table"];
    GridView_DataTable.DataSource = data_table;
    GridView_DataTable.DataBind();
}
```

What I am trying to do is to get database data from the server, put it in a data table, send the data table to a client and bind that data table to a grid view.

When I attempt to run the client and enter "GetAllCreditCards" to the variable function, the server project comes up with the following error:

```
A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'.
```

What am I doing wrong?  I just want to pass the database data and bind it to a grid view on the client side, that's all.

**EDIT**

It seems that the JavaScriptSerializer cannot serialize a Data Table.  Then how can I send the records from the server to the client and bind them to the grid view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is there is a problem with the javascript serializing which you are doing please have a look here if this helps [A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'SubSonic.Schema .DatabaseColumn'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153385/a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-subsonic)