# WinForm button click event to convert c# data to html code? (unexperienced C# user)

Tags: c#, html, winforms, button

I have been trying to find a way or code that will convert c# data to html code/html template by a ButtonClick but have just found some converters that convert C# code to HTML code and thats not what i need. Its by a ButtonClick that i need C# data that is filled in by users in the program this data is texts and images. Cant provide any code cause i only got the front end UI designed nothing else and i got to low reputation to upload a pic =)

P.S i am a noob at C# done some things in C# in the past but have forgot alot when i havent been working with it for years.

Comment: Please don't recreate the same question twice in a row without any useful information. Instead of adding whole bunch "I'm new/know nothing/searched a lot" it would be better to explain what you actually try to do. I suspect you want Winform app to submit data to a web page via POST request...

Comment: send me the photo and I can post it for you

Comment: yeah, kind of Alexei okey then i will provide false info next time to sound smart and well researched....

Comment: yeah its something in that direction you know anything about it alexei ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a hunch that you are attempting to submit data from your server side to a client side web page via POST.
If this is the case, the stages would be as follows:

1. The **web page** will **send a request to the server**. You might want to use a full postback or an ajax call. If you are a newbie, the full postback would be easier for you.
2. The **Server side** will **fetch** required data (the `C# data`).
3. The **server will wrap up** the `C# data` to a structure that can be parsed by the client side.
4. The **server** will **send** the wrapped up data back to the client.

### Details:

The part you asking about is #3 (wrapping up the data to a structure that can be parsed by the client side ).
In order to do so I suggest using a [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) as described in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201529/turn-c-sharp-object-into-a-json-string-in-net-4) (including code example...).

In case your data is an object that has many redundant properties that are not required by the client side, I would also consider using anonymous types for sending only required data. You can find an example for how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153385/a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-subsonic/1153396#1153396)