# C# seralize dynamic object with EF result in it (Create JSON object from dynamic c# object)

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, serialization, dynamic

I have this code:

```
var companyDetails = db.tbl_Mallstore.ToList();

dynamic result = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
result.count = 1;
result.company = companyDetails.FirstOrDefault();

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string output = serializer.Serialize(result);
```

That throws the error:

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'eDurar.Models.tbl_Mallstore

In this case it works:

```
dynamic result = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
result.count = count;
result.store_name = companyDetails.FirstOrDefault().store_name;

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(result);
```

Comment: Why use dynamic ? I'm pretty sure that it can be serialized using the custom class with 2 properties.

Comment: @mybirthname to avoid unnecessary declaration of class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153385/a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-subsonic

Answer (score 0):

I had to specify manually the fields needed. I think there is some circular reference inside the other data.

```
int count = 0;

var companyDetails = db.tbl_Mallstore.ToList();

count = companyDetails.Count();

dynamic result = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
result.count = count;
if (count > 0)
{
    result.store = companyDetails.Select(x => new { x.store_name, x.store_id }).FirstOrDefault();
}

return this.Json(result);
```