# unable to bind the json result to the table using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC controller where I am converting the datatable result using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` and returning as follows

```
public JsonResult GetJson(DateTime StartDate)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetDetails"))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@startdate", SqlDbType.DateTime);
                    cmd.Parameters["@startdate"].Value = StartDate;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }
            }
            return Json(new { success = true, data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt) },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

But the same is working inside fiddle when I copy the result that I am getting

https://jsfiddle.net/szq2ker4/1/
This is how I am making an ajax call in jquery and doing the rest as per fiddle but I am not seeing the expected as per in the fiddle

```
$.get("/controller/GetJson", { StartDate: date},
function (response) { var result = JSON.parse(response.data);})
```

The result I am getting is as follows, can some one let me know where I am doing wrong

[image]

Console response
[image]

```
$.get("/controller/GetJson", { StartDate: date},
function (response) { var result = JSON.parse(response.data);}).fail(function (response) { **alert('failed')**;});
```

Comment: what you get when you log `response` in `success`?

Comment: Added the response

Comment: `return Json()` already serializes your object. Doing it a 2nd time using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dt)` and then using `JSON.parse(response.data)` makes no sense

Comment: You might only need to use `JSON.parse(response)` and yea as @StephenMuecke said there is no need to wrap it again with `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`

Comment: If I use `return Json(new { success = true, data = dt },
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` it is giving me 500 error

Comment: What are the details of the error (that means that the server code is throwing an exception) Use you browser tools (the Network Tab) to inspect the response. (and I assume you have also changed it to just `var result = response.data;`)

Comment: After returning data as follows `Json(new { success = true, data = dt }` it is not entering in to this code at all`function (response) {`

Comment: It is givng me 500 error after controller returns

Comment: Read my previous comment - use your browser tools!

Comment: I have used and I am getting `500 internal server error`

Comment: I have added `fail` and it is entering in to that and when I see the response text it is showing as `500 internal server error`

Comment: FGS Use your browser tools to inspect the response - it contains the full details of your error!!

Comment: This is the error I am getting `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule'.`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153385/a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type-subsonic) here on slack that may help you:

> It seems that there are circular references in your object hierarchy
>   which is not supported by the JSON serializer. Do you need all the
>   columns? You could pick up only the properties you need in the view:

```
return Json(new 
{  
    PropertyINeed1 = data.PropertyINeed1,
    PropertyINeed2 = data.PropertyINeed2
});
```

> This will make your JSON object lighter and easier to understand. If
>   you have many properties, AutoMapper could be used to automatically
>   map between DTO objects and View objects.